# Selecção de células

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu preciso de selecionar a linha com o valor da combobox 1 e com a data da combobox 3 para selecionar logo a linha pretendida para eliminar. Este é o problema que tenho para resolver.

Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Este é o código que tenho para seleccionar a célula da combobox1:

```
Private Sub RemverRegisto_Click()
Range("E3").Select

While ActiveCell <> ""
If CB_TipoFralda.Text = ActiveCell Then
Resposta = MsgBox("Registo encontrado, deseja excluir?", vbYesNo)
End If
If Resposta = vbYes Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Exit Sub
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Vou colocar uma imagem para mostrar o que pretendo:

Quero ativar a linha com os valores da combobox produto e da data para eliminar e com o código acima só ativo a linha com o valor da combobox produto, logo precorre todas as linhas em que encontra o produto da combobox1.

Já consegui chegar à solução, obrigado.

Se precisarem de ver a solução é só pedirem que eu coloco aqui

Comment: Será que coloco perguntas difíceis, será que não faço as perguntas de uma forma correta ou será por ser eu a colocar as perguntas que dificilmente alguém me responde ou ajuda. Ainda não consegui perceber onde está o problema.

Comment: Primeiro de tudo Bruno, é preciso paciencia! Lembre-se que o site é comunitário, as vezes usuários que entendem do tema da sua pergunta não estão online ou não viram sua pergunta ainda. A dica que lhe dou é sempre seguir as orientações de [ask] e procurar ser sucinto e objetivo na dúvida, procurando focar apenas no problema.

Comment: Boa noite, já vi que não estou a desempenhar um bom papel no fórum, mas também só o estou a utilizar há 2 ou 3 dias e não estou a ser compreendido pela comunidade. Na vida deitar alguém a baixo é fácil, fazer a diferença ao contrário é que é difícil e cada vez mais. O que quero dizer, é que como sou novo no fórum onde precisava da ajuda da comunidade, o que está acontecer é o contrário, é a comunidade julgar me e não ajudar......isso qualquer um faz o contrário é que é difícil infelizmente......mas obrigado a todos mesmo assim.

Comment: @Bruno não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "não estou a ser compreendido pela comunidade", vc fala da pergunta? Ela precisa ser mais clara, se vc puder isolar o problema num [exemplo minimo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) já ajuda muito. Em qual momento a comunidade esta a te julgar também? Pelo contrário, o diegofm esta tetando ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado por me estarem ajudar, acham que assim a minha dúvida está mais clara ou preciso de melhorar? Sabem que são os meus primeiros passos no fórum e quero ser bem recebido pela comunidade

Comment: O que preciso de melhorar na pergunta? Estou mesmo a precisar de ajuda nesta questão com alguma urgência.......

Comment: Posso só perguntar o motivo de não ter recebido ajuda de ninguém da comunidade? 
Vou colocar algumas opções:
1- Não consegui colocar a minha dúvida de uma forma clara?
2- Era um problema difícil de resolver e a comunidade não conseguiu ajudar?
3- Outro motivo.

Só pergunto isto para saber onde tenho de melhorar uma vez que sou novo na comunidade e pretendo ajudar e ser ajudado por vocês

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, acho que seu código deveria ficar parecido com esse abaixo:

```
Private Sub RemverRegisto_Click()
'declaração de variáveis
    dim linha as long
    dim flag as boolean
'iniciação das variáveis
    linha=3
    flag=false
'inicia o procedimento
    do
        if cells(linha,5).value = CB_TipoFralda.Text and cells(linha,3).value = CB_DataSaida.Text then
            flag=true
            Resposta = MsgBox("Registo encontrado, deseja excluir?", vbYesNo)
            If Resposta = vbYes Then
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
                exit sub
            else
                exit sub
            end if
        else
            linha=linha+1
        end if
    loop until cells(linha,5).value="" or flag=true
end sub
```

Obs1: troque o nome de CB_DataSaida pelo nome da sua combobox de data de saida.

Obs2: eu supus que o nome da sua combobox1 é CB_TipoFralda, se não for substitua o pelo nome correspondente.

Obs3: Todos nós trabalhamos e temos várias coisas para fazer, não é sempre que dá para parar a vida e vir aos tópicos e responder. Então, ter paciência é fundamental.